About using xlUDF in Excel C++ SDK
I'm trying to create an XLL add-in function, which will inside call another custom function, which is defined using Excel Javascript Add-In. Don't ask why, two different parties are developing, and one js custom function should be called from C++ code.
According to the "official" documentation of xlUDF method, this could be done.
However, since I'm very rusty in C++, I could not make this work. The sample codes on Microsoft sites don't work, marked erroneous in the IDE. I tried some GPT stuff, but could not get a working answer. The following code block (the last one from chatgpt) gives two errors on compile:
double WINAPI xll_addfive(double x)
{
#pragma XLLEXPORT

    try
    {
        XLOPER12 xRetVal, xUDF, xInp, xVal;

        // Set up xUDF (replace with your UDF name)
        xUDF.xltype = xltypeStr;
        xUDF.val.str = (XCHAR*)L"QUALITYCHK"; // Replace with your UDF name

        // Set up xInp (numeric input)
        xInp.xltype = xltypeNum;
        xInp.val.num = x;

        // Set up xVal (additional input, e.g., 5)
        xVal.xltype = xltypeNum;
        xVal.val.num = 5;

        // Set up an array of XLOPER12 structures to hold the arguments
        XLOPER12 args[2] = { xInp, xVal };

        // Call Excel12 function
        Excel12(xlUDF, &xRetVal, &xUDF, &xInp, &xVal);
        
        // Extract result (assuming it's numeric)
        double result = xRetVal.val.num;

        // Free memory returned by Excel
        Excel12(xlFree, NULL, 1, &xRetVal);

        return result;
    }
    catch (const std::exception&)
    {
        std::cout << "error\n";
        return 0.0; // Handle error gracefully
    }
}

Errors:
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'XLOPER12 **' to '_Ty'
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'const int *' to '_Ty'

I need a real intelligence here. How can it be done? Am I on the right track?

Any indication from the compiler of which line(s) are causing the error?

This is the reference for xlUDF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/xludf. Looks like you are missing the parameter count argument (3rd) which should probably be 3?

Also in the MS help, they cast the parameters to (LPXLOPER12) ... not sure if that makes a difference.

I do not need to implement this code any more, but for the responses... I've tried as in the documentation (parameter count argument), no success. LPXLOPER12 casting, no success. I do not have the compiler output anymore, but it was like "invalid signature" or something, the method did not match in any case. I'll let the question stay here, if anyone gets similar problems or any solutions, that will help future generations.
